# Is the Azure DocumentDB service still in Preview mode?

Tags: azure

In the Azure Portal, DocumentDB shows up in "Preview" mode

[image: portal screenshot]

However, in the documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/), it says that they have 99.99% uptime in the SLA

Is DocumentDB production-grade already? Can I use it for a production deployment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Azure is in perpetual early access. All I'm waiting for now is for Microsoft to start charging for DLC and announce a merger between their gaming and Azure division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document DB the service has been GA since 2015 and is in the portal listed as NoSQL (Document DB). What's in your screenshot is a newer service which provides [Mongo DB protocol support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb) on top of Document DB, this service is in preview.

It's not very clear how this effects your SLA, you should still get the 99.99% for the underlying Document DB, but the Mongo API may have a lower SLA. I can't find any documentation to confirm this.

Comment: There are 2 options in the "databases" option - one is "mongoDB as a service Preview", the other is "documentDB with mongoDB support" - the first one is supposedly in preview, the second one isn't - it seems the Azure people forgot to remove one option or the other